# VSCode visualize dynamic arrays in debugger

Tags: ubuntu, c++11, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using VSCode in Ubuntu for some C++ code.

With the following code:

```
int array [10] = {1};
```

I can visualize the entries of the array in the debugger:

[image]

However, when I dynamically allocate the array, with:

int* array = new int[10];

I get:

[image]

Is it possible to visualize the dynamic array as the one allocated with:

```
int array [10] = {1};
```

Even if I type:

```
array,10
```

in the WATCH window, I will only see one entry.

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 1):

Worked by typing in the WATCH window:

```
*array@10
```

For shared pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> teste (new int[10]);
```

Visualize it with:

```
*(teste.get())@10
```